# Lots of errors when trying to deploy a create-react-app to github pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, github-pages

Im learning React so i did a project to solidify what i learned and now that i finished i want to host it on a github pages, i knew it would be different from the standard projects i did and how i set up a github pages up until now and because i haven't done this before, i searched around how to do that and found some tutorials and the documentation, i followed them.

But instead of the app being hosted it's just the README file that's being displayed on the actual github pages and the script didn't create a new a gh-pages branch on my repo like it should do

Here's the errors in terminal

```
> react-recipe-api@0.1.0 predeploy D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
> npm run build


> react-recipe-api@0.1.0 build D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  50.79 KB  build\static\js\2.56be15e5.chunk.js
  1.55 KB   build\static\js\main.5045ac4c.chunk.js
  785 B     build\static\js\runtime-main.781931a1.js
  775 B     build\static\css\main.f7628ea1.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /react-recipe-finder/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at https://nicoding0.github.io/react-recipe-finder , run:

  npm run deploy

Find out more about deployment here:

  hxxps://bitly/CRA-deploy


> react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn git'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'git'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'config'←[39m, ←[32m'user.name'←[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-13T13_45_56_265Z-debug.log
```

Here's the log file content:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: react-recipe-api@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;;C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Roaming\npm
8 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
9 silly lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: react-recipe-api@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;;C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\scorpio\AppData\Roaming\npm
14 verbose lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
15 silly lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle react-recipe-api@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
19 verbose pkgid react-recipe-api@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd D:\Documents\Git-repo\finished\react-recipe-api
21 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v12.13.0
24 verbose npm  v6.12.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the react-recipe-api@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-recipe-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://nicoding0.github.io/react-recipe-finder",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

I really don't know what's wrong and i'm kinda lost, i did follow all the steps but i think i got mixed up in the order a bit.

I know Github Pages looks for an index.html in root to display on the page but npm run build creates a new folder with a compiled index.html. If anyone can help, i'd be very grateful, thank you.

Edit: Oh and here's the page: https://nicoding0.github.io/react-recipe-finder/

and my repo: https://github.com/Nicoding0/react-recipe-finder

Edit2: I just tested on a brand new react app created with create-react-app and the same happens, so that tells me it's a problem on my end, what is wrong with my stuff?

Comment: The easiest way I'd suggest is to create a branch named `gh-pages` using your build folder content, push the branch and finally update your github repository settings (Settings -> Options -> Github Pages -> Source -> gh-pages branch).

Comment: @pritam why didn't i think of that workaround, that still doesn't clarify why it's throwing so many errors at me, but thanks anyway